# Can anyone explain to me what "热闹的嬉笑怒骂外加弹唱小曲" means?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase, idioms

I'm really confused about what the idiom '嬉笑怒骂' in this sentence means.

Answer (score 3):

嬉笑怒骂 is a common expression

嬉笑 (playfully laugh); 怒骂 (angrily scold)

**嬉笑怒骂** means "**to ridicule**" (ironically and/ or bluntly )

[热闹的][嬉笑怒骂][外加][弹唱小曲]

[lively][ridicule][plus extra][playing of little song]

"弹唱小曲 (play little song)" -- "**sing song about it**" is the third way of ridiculing beside "**playfully laugh**" and "**angrily scold**"

> "热闹的嬉笑怒骂外加弹唱小曲” means: " lively ridicule every which way and more"

Answer (score 0):

in china we never be quiet when we have dinner,even in the restautrant we do much worse,cause everyone is talking loud,if you want to your friends hear what you are talking you have to talk louder,then we get louder and lounder.so what you asking,it is qiute like you and your friends have dinner in a resraurant,you are talking about something funny or a joke,and some singer or singers sing a country music song